# Set attribution when using google maps api with openstreetmap map tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a website (actually walksinspain.org) which displays maps using the Google Maps API, and users can select which map to display using a control. However some of the map tiles used are from OpenStreetMap, and for these I'd like to set the correct attribution in the bottom right hand corner of the map.

When a user selects to display an ordinary Google map then it shows "Map Data ©2023 Inst. Geogr. Nacional" and when a Satellite map it shows "Map Data ©2023 Inst. Geogr. Nacional Imagery ©2023 TerraMetrics". However, when an OpenStreetMap map is shown the text is simply "Image may be subject to copyright". I'd like to change this to the proper OSM attribution eg "© OpenStreetMap contributors".

I can't see anything in the API [ImageMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/image-overlay#ImageMapType) or [ImageMapTypeOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/image-overlay#ImageMapTypeOptions) classes which would allow me to set this.

The best I've come up with is a kludge - looking for the html element which contains the attribution and overwrite it when the map type is selected, eg:

```
map.addListener('maptypeid_changed', function() {
        let mapType = map.getMapTypeId();
        if (mapType === "OSM") {
            setTimeout(() => {
                spanElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.gmnoprint > div.gm-style-cc span");
                spanElements.forEach(function(item) {
                    item.innerHTML = `© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>`;
                    });
            }, "500");
        }
    });
```

The delay is needed because the event is triggered before the google maps api code redraws the map, including writing that text string.

However, this solution doesn't really work because the text string is rewritten by google every time the map is moved or zoomed etc, so I'd have to capture all those sorts of events too.

Of course, I could do the attribution outside the map, but it would be nice to have it in the usual place if at all possible. Does anyone know how that might be done?

Comment: You can't, but you could write text on the map with a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls).

Comment: Thanks @MrUpsidown for the confirmation - I suspected that was the case. I've raised a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279997251) on the google maps tracker. It'll be interesting to see if that goes anywhere.

Comment: Don't expect anything to happen soon though, even if they approve your FR.